# Setting specific date format VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a unique problem for which I was not able to find a solution in the forum. I have an excel sheet where I take in date inputs through list down options. 3 cells have list down as Date(D1), Month(M1), Year (Z1) respectively. I have a button macro which picks up the value of the cells and  also parallel through VLOOKUP the month name is converted to the month number and thus the output is a String with right format (DD/MM/YYYY). I used DateSerial combined with Format. So far so good!

```
Y1 = Format(DateSerial(Z1, M1, D1), "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

However now to convert this string to a date I am using CDate. If I have a regional date setting of US (format MM/DD/YYYY) then the CDate is converting the date to the local time format. I however need this (DD/MM/YYYY) format for future use. How can I get an output in specific format irrespective of the local date format? Is there any other solution? Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit:
Y1 is declared as a String. When it was declared as Date, the date already appeared in regional format inspite of the format condition. I also tried the format function with the "" symbol as below but it gives me an overflow error.

```
Y1 = Format(DateSerial(Z1, M1, D1), DD / MM / YYYY)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. If I store as Date (here for example Dim Y1 as Date), it still stores the date in the MM/DD/YYYY format based on the local format.

Comment: Hence whenever you need the specific format, use `Format`... on a `Date` variable. "However now to convert this string to a date I am using `CDate`" ... why? That's going backwards. You had a `Date` with `DateSerial`.

Comment: I was doing so because at first step with Date format it was giving me the local setting format. Atleast as a string it would show me the right format and I was able to find out where it was changing. I also tried using a MakeEUDate() function similar to MakeUSDate() function but still the problem persists

Comment: If you want a `Date`: `Dim myDate As Date`, `myDate = DateSerial(Z1, M1, D1)`. `Y1` is the correctly formatted `String`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks again. Even when I do so, the date appears in local format.

Comment: How it appears to you is *irrelevant*. Use the correctly-formatted `String` when you need to control the format.

Comment: In other words, a [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-data-type) is a floating-point number. It is displayed to you "according to the short date format recognized by your computer." If you want a consistent format, then use a `String`, as you are doing. If you want a `Date` variable, then remember that it's just a number.

Comment: I am not sure if I get you, I apologize in advance as i am still a learner.  Do you mean I should declare Y1 as a date? I have done so and the problem is that I need the date format in the above specified format for future use. I use it  ahead where I compare it with a predefined date structure (For example, 31/03/XXXX) and other steps follows. So if the date for example is (01/06/XXXX)  and due to regional setting it becomes (06/01/XXXX) and this messes up the comparison. The declaring as string step was to just check where I was failing.

Comment: As mentioned, if you need a specific format, use a `String`. If you need a `Date`, then use a `Date`. Would be curious to see what you mean by this "comparison".

Comment: Now in your example, Even if I apply the format setting to myDate it still shows me the local date setting.

Comment: okay. let me explain the "comparison" a little bit. I am using this Y1 a start date and Y2 as an end date and want to divide some values between the quarters the dates are in. For example, if I have to divide 100$ between Y1(01/01/2021) and Y2(12/04/2021), I am checking what Quarter of the year the dates fall into by comparing against 31/03/XXXX or 30/07/XXXX etc) and thus dividing the 100$ between the quarters. The problem arises when US date format is taken and thus the system cannot properly calculate the "Quarter"

Comment: That's your problem. Don't compare against a `String` version of the date. Use a `Date` variable and for example the `Month` and `Year` functions.

Comment: To determine the quarter of the year using "real dates" and not strings, merely use `=INT((MONTH(theDate)-1)/3)+1` and format as `General` or `Number`

Comment: Could you share the complete code so we can see why you need to convert the date to a string in the first place? It seems unlikely that you need to do this at all.

Comment: Actually, in VBA, you can determine the quarter with `datepart("q",theDate)`

Comment: Thank you all. The solutions worked. I was comparing a date with a string and now I have corrected it. You guys are the best

Answer (score 0):

Set the date *value* (which has no format):

```
Y1 = DateSerial(Z1, M1, D1)
```

Then to Y1, apply the *format* you prefer, i.e.:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```